# $A⇒(B \lor C)$ and $[(A \Rightarrow B) \lor (A \Rightarrow C)]$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

[(A⇒ B∨C)] ⇒ [A⇒(¬B⇒C)] ⇒[(A⇒¬B)⇒(A⇒C)] ⇒ [¬(A⇒¬B)∨(A⇒C)]⇒[(A∧B)∨(A⇒C)]

[(A⇒B)∨(A⇒C)] is equivalent to A⇒(B∨C).

Can I prove [(A∧B)∨(A⇒C)]  ⇒ [A⇒(B V C)]? or is there problem in the proof above

Please don't use truth table to prove. But only deduction rules.
A∨B by definition ¬A⇒B
Deduction rules:

1) A⇒(B⇒ A)

2) [A⇒(B⇒C)]⇒[(A⇒B)⇒(A⇒C)]

3) [A⇒B]⇒ [¬B⇒¬A]

Comment: You have to assume also a definition for $A \land B$, in order to prove :  $[(A \land B) \lor (A⇒C)] \Leftrightarrow [A⇒(B  \lor C)]$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Oh yes I forgot to mention. A∧B stands for ¬(A⇒¬B)

Comment: For the part : $[A⇒(B∨C)] ⇒ [(A∧B)∨(A⇒C)]$, with the appriopriate substitutions, we have : $[A⇒(\lnot B ⇒ C)] ⇒ [\lnot \lnot (A ⇒ \lnot B) ⇒ (A⇒C)]$. This is simply an instance of A3), **provided that** we have proved *Double Negation* : $\lnot \lnot A ⇒ A$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA this part I also proved in first line. But I am unable to prove [(A⇒B)∨(A⇒C)] is equivalent to A⇒(B∨C). And to answer Can I prove [(A∧B)∨(A⇒C)] ⇒ [A⇒(B V C)]?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I have proved double negation also

Comment: Are you sure to be able to prove *Double Negation* with A3) ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA use MP also. A⇒[(A⇒A)⇒A](usingA1) then [A⇒(A⇒A)]⇒[A⇒A] (using A2).  And A⇒(A⇒A) using A1 and Mp we get A⇒A.

Comment: Now as proved in last comment B⇒B. So ¬A⇒¬A. Now using A3 we get double negation

Comment: You have proved $A⇒A$ and with it and A3), by *modus ponens*, you get : $¬A⇒¬A$. But this is **not** *Double Negation* : $¬¬A⇒A$.

Comment: Ya I got it. A3 is not sufficient to prove double negation. We should take [A⇒¬B]⇒ [B⇒¬A] axiom @MauroALLEGRANZA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the part:

> $[(A∧B)∨(A⇒C)]⇒[A⇒(B∨C)]$

we first replace $\lor$ and $\land$ with their definition in terms of $\lnot$ and $⇒$:

> $A∨B$ stands for $¬A⇒B$ and $A∧B$ stands for $¬(A⇒¬B)$.

Applying them to the above formula, we get:

> $[(A⇒¬B)⇒(A⇒C)]⇒[A⇒(¬B⇒C)]$.

In addition, we assume that we have available the *Deduction Th*, that is provable (together with $A ⇒ A$) from A1) and A2) only.

---

1) $[(A⇒¬B)⇒(A⇒C)]$ --- assumed [a]

2) $A$ --- assumed [b]

3) $¬B$ --- assumed [c]

4) $¬B⇒(A⇒¬B)$ --- axiom A1)

5) $A⇒¬B$ --- from 3) and 4) by *Modus Ponens*

6) $A⇒C$ --- from 1) and 5) by *Modus Ponens*

7) $C$ --- from 2) and 6) by *Modus Ponens*

8) $¬B⇒C$ --- from 3) and 7) by *Deduction Th*, discharging [c]

9) $A ⇒(¬B⇒C)$ --- from 2) and 8) by *Deduction Th*, discharging [b]

> 10) $[(A⇒¬B)⇒(A⇒C)]⇒[A⇒(¬B⇒C)]$ --- from 1) and 9) by *Deduction Th*, discharging [a].

Comment: You are using Deduction Theorem. But we have not proved Deduction theorem yet. Can we prove it from A1, A2 and A3 using MP

Comment: @Sushil - you can find the proof of *DT* (using A1 and a2) in many textbooks, and also in some post on this site...

Comment: can you please just state DT

Comment: @Sushil - you can see the proof [here](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Philosophy/Logic/Deduction/4-deductionTheorem.htm).

Comment: This proof is by induction. Can we prove it without induction also.

Comment: I am accepting the proof because you completely given the answer. It was a new question to prove deduction theorem from A1 and A2 without inductive argument which I have asked in separate question.

Comment: Sorry but I relaized it today: You proved [(A⇒¬B)⇒(A⇒C)]⇒[A⇒(¬B⇒C)]. But my question is:  [(¬(A⇒B))   ⇒   (A⇒C)]   ⇒   [A  ⇒  (¬B⇒C)].   Are you using (¬(A⇒B)) ⇒ (A⇒¬B). If yes How it follows only using the axiom schema given.