# Formal proof of $(A\lor B)∨C \leftrightarrow A\lor(B\lor C)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

$A\lor B$ by definition $\neg A\implies B$

Deduction rules:

1. $A\implies (B\implies A)$
2. $(A\implies (B\implies C))\implies ((A\implies B)\implies(A\implies C))$
3. $(\neg B\implies \neg A)\implies(A\implies B)$

These are axiom schemas

How to prove $(A\lor B)∨C \iff A\lor(B\lor C)$

where we need to prove $(A\lor B)∨C \implies A\lor(B\lor C)$ and $A\lor(B\lor C) \implies (A\lor B)∨C$

This is not a homework problem.

Comment: Your question is confusing. You use the symbols '<--->' and '⇒'. Regarding the first one, is it part of the language? Regarding both of them, why use '⇒' instead of '-->'? Regarding the problem itself, have you learned the deduction theorem?

Comment: <---> is biconditional symbol

Comment: As @GitGud wrote, you need to be more precise in what you want. Can you rewrite the statement to use only negation and implication?

Comment: I have not proved deduction theorem till now. Infact I want to prove deduction theorem using 1), 2) and 3)

Comment: A⇒(B⇒ A) is one of our axiom @GitGud

Comment: @SushilI I edited the question,but my question still remains. It seems as though $\leftrightarrow$ isn't part of the language, so you need to explain what does it abbreviate, otherwise the question is meaningless. Also, to be perfectly rigorous, there are parentheses missing to make the formulas well formed.

Comment: To prove A ↔ B we need to prove A⇒B and B⇒A @GitGud

Comment: [(A∨B)∨C]↔[A∨(B∨C)]. Does it make sense now? @GitGud

Comment: Check how equivalence is defined in your system. You may need to prove two statements: $((A\lor B)\lor C)\implies (A\lor (B\lor C))$ and $(A\lor (B\lor C))\implies ((A\lor B)\lor C)$. If "logical and" is defined in your system you can combine those two statements into one.

Comment: @RoryDaulton right I want to prove both.(or prove atleast 1 other will become obvious I think)

Comment: You haven't quite finished explaining your logical system. Do you also have the substitution rule of inference, so that from $A\implies(B\implies A)$ I can immediately get $\lnot A\implies(B\implies \lnot A)$? Or is *modus ponens* your only rule of inference and those axioms are actually axiom schemas?

Comment: These are axiom of schemas. @RoryDaulton

Comment: And modus ponens is rule of inference @RoryDaulton

Comment: I'm guessing you are not supposed to use truth tables are you?

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow no only 3 axiom schemas, MP rule and definition of A∨B.(If you like you can use DT if you can prove Dt from 3 axiom schemas and MP without inductive arguement

Comment: By definition $X \vee Y \iff \lnot X \implies Y$, so by Axiom 3, we have $[X \lor Y] \implies [\lnot X \implies Y] \implies [\lnot Y \implies X] \implies [Y \lor X]$. Since choice of symbols is arbitrary, $[Y \lor X] \implies [X \lor Y]$ too. So $"\vee"$ is commutative, i.e. $(X \lor Y) \iff (Y \vee X)$. Not sure if this will be of any use in proving associativity.

Comment: Yes commutativity proved easily but what about associativity. That is main problem I am facing @Marconius

Comment: Is $\lnot$ defined as $\Rightarrow\bot$?  Or is axiom 3 the only thing we know about $\lnot$?

Comment: Axiom 3 is all about ¬(negation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my answer to your previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359135/a%e2%87%92b-lor-c-and-a-rightarrow-b-lor-a-rightarrow-c) , I'll assume that we have available the *Deduction Th*, that is provable (together with $\vdash A ⇒ A$) from A1) and A2) only.

---

For : $[¬A⇒(¬B⇒C)] \Leftrightarrow [¬(¬A⇒B)⇒C]$, we need some preliminary *Lemma* :

> *Lemma 1* : $A ⇒ B, B ⇒ C \vdash A ⇒ C$ --- *Syllogism* "derived rule" : easily provable with *DT*
>
> *Lemma 2* : $¬¬A ⇒ A$ --- *Double Negation* :

a) $¬¬A ⇒ (¬¬¬¬A ⇒ ¬¬A)$ --- axiom A1)

b) $(¬¬¬¬A ⇒ ¬¬A) ⇒ (¬A ⇒ ¬¬¬A)$ --- axiom A3)

c)  $¬¬A ⇒ (¬A ⇒ ¬¬¬A)$ --- from a) and b) by *Lemma 1*

d) $(¬A ⇒ ¬¬¬A) ⇒ (¬¬A ⇒ A)$ --- axiom A3)

e) $¬¬A ⇒ (¬¬A ⇒ A)$ --- from c) and d) by *Lemma 1*

f) $(¬¬A ⇒ (¬¬A ⇒ A)) ⇒ [(¬¬A ⇒ ¬¬A) ⇒ (¬¬A ⇒ A)]$ --- axiom A2)

g) $¬¬A ⇒ A$ --- from e), f) and $\vdash ¬A ⇒ ¬A$, by *MP* twice.

> *Lemma 3* : $A ⇒ ¬¬A$ --- *Double Negation* :

a) $¬¬¬A ⇒ ¬A$ --- *Lemma 2*

b) $(¬¬¬A ⇒ ¬A) ⇒ (A ⇒ ¬¬A)$ --- axiom A3)

c) $A ⇒ ¬¬A$ --- from a) and b) by *MP*.

> *Lemma 4* : $(¬B ⇒ A) ⇒ (¬A ⇒ B)$ --- provable from axiom A3), with *Lemma 2* and *Lemma 1*.
>
> *Lemma 5* : $(A ⇒ B) ⇒ (¬¬A ⇒ ¬¬B)$ --- provable from *Lemma 2*, *Lemma 3* and *Lemma 1*.
>
> *Lemma 6* : $(A ⇒ B) ⇒ (¬B ⇒ ¬A)$ --- provable from *Lemma 5*, axiom A3) and *Lemma 1*.
>
> *Lemma 7* : $¬A⇒(¬B⇒¬(¬A⇒B))$ :

a) $¬A ⇒ ((¬A⇒B) ⇒ B)$ --- from $¬A, ¬A ⇒ B \vdash B$ and *DT*

b) $((¬A⇒B) ⇒ B) ⇒ (¬B ⇒ ¬(¬A⇒B))$ --- *Lemma 6*

c) $¬A ⇒ (¬B ⇒ ¬(¬A⇒B))$ --- from a) and b) by *Lemma 1*.

---

Now for the main proof :

1) $¬(¬A⇒B)⇒C$ --- premise

2) $¬A$ --- assumed [a]

3) $¬B$ --- assumed [b]

4) $¬(¬A⇒B)$ --- from 2), 3) and *Lemma 7*, by *Modus Ponens* twice

5) $C$ --- from 4) and 1) by *MP*

6) $¬B⇒C$ --- from 3) and 5) by *Deduction Th*, discharging assumption [b]

7) $¬A⇒(¬B⇒C)$ --- from 2) and 6) by *Deduction Th*, discharging assumption [a]

> 8) $[¬(¬A⇒B)⇒C] ⇒ [¬A⇒(¬B⇒C)]$ --- from 1) and 7), discharging the premise 1)

---

9) $¬A⇒(¬B⇒C)$ --- premise

10) $¬A$ --- assumed [c]

11) $¬B ⇒ C$ --- from 9) and 10) by *MP*

12) $¬C ⇒ B$ --- from 11) and *Lemma 4* by *MP*

13) $¬C$ --- assumed [d]

14) $B$ --- from 13) and 12) by *MP*

15) $¬A ⇒ B$ --- from 10) and 14) by *DT*, discharging assumption [c]

16) $¬C ⇒ (¬A ⇒ B)$ --- from 13) and 15) by *DT*, discharging assumption [d]

17) $¬(¬A ⇒ B) ⇒ C$ --- from 16) and *Lemma 4* by *MP*

> 18) $[¬A⇒(¬B⇒C)] ⇒ [¬(¬A ⇒ B) ⇒ C]$ --- from 9) and 17) by *DT*, discharging the premise 9).

---

> > 16) The *bi-conditional* follows from 8) and 18).

Comment: Whew. Can you please also outline proof of Lemma 2 and Lemma 3? Rest all Lemma's proof I got

Comment: @Sushil - but in your comment to a previous [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359135/a%e2%87%92b-lor-c-and-a-rightarrow-b-lor-a-rightarrow-c) you said "I have proved double negation also" ...

Comment: Oh I just forgot to correct that mistake. sorry I had proved using axiom (¬B⇒A)⇒(¬A⇒B). Not the (¬B⇒¬A)⇒(A⇒B). I wants to correct that there. But can you please atleast give me some hint.